# (SyntaxError): missing ] after element list when autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I get following error (SyntaxError): missing ] after element list when using Jquery autocomplete function.If i can use static values then its working fine but with dyanamic foreach loop it will display error,so I don't undestand where is error.Here is my code:-

```
        jQuery(function() {
        jQuery.noConflict();
       var availableTags = [
       <?php foreach( $search_categories as $search_categories5 )
       { 
            echo $search_categories5->name; 
       } ?>
       ];

      jQuery( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
       });
     });
```

Anyone can help me.

Comment: view the rendered code.... view source.

Comment: Array objects should have trailing `,` [{},{},{}]

Comment: The issue is each element in object is enclosed with ' and ,

Comment: Try the answer provided by me, its working fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
    <?php
    $array = ['One', 'Two'];
    ?>
    var availableTags = [
        <?php
            foreach($array as $val)
            {
                echo "'".$val."', ";
            }
        ?>
    ];
    $(function(){
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });  
</script>
```

Its working

Comment: Sounds great !!

Comment: Accept the answer if it helps you :D